# 500 error after mod_fcgid error

Tags: apache-2.2, 500-error, mod-fcgid

I have this error on my sever:

```
        [Mon Feb 27 09:56:03 2012] [error] mod_fcgid: 
process /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web111/.php-fcgi-starter(7847) 
    exit(communication error), get unexpected signal 11
```

And then get 500 error.

What can i do with this?

Comment: What information do I show? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the previous person said, I'm pretty sure "signal 11″ is a segmentation fault, which would seem to indicate an invalid memory access attempt. I've found the most common issues to be:

1. Incorrect File/Folder Permissions,
2. Bad Code, or Incorrect Syntax in the .htaccess File, or...
3. Incorrect php.ini Configuration

Comment: The link provided is dead

Answer (score 2):

There's not nearly enough information here to make any sort of determination about what's going on. All I can tell you is that signal 11 is a segmentation fault, which which indicates an invalid memory access attempt. Usually this is because of some programming error in the C code.

Comment: What information do I show you?